# Moving records from one table to another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form that performs a search query on table `A`, which outputs the result on a subform on the same form.

What I want to do is to add in a button that will move selected records on the subform into table `B`, deletes the records from table `A` (which I assume will be similar in principle to what I want to do below), then requeries the search, which I assume can be done with something as simple as `me.requery`.

```
strID = Me.Form1_subform.Form.ID.Value
strSQL = "INSERT INTO B ([a], [b], [c]) "
strSQL = strSQL + "SELECT [a], [b], [c] "
strSQL = strSQL + "From A"
strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE [ID] = " & strID
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

The above is my attempt to insert records from `A` into `B`. Right now, the above code only performs the operation on the first of many selected records (it works as expected, but I can't seem to find out how to get Access to recognize that other records are being selected). Is there a simple way of performing a loop of the above code in Access? I am currently only able to get Access to work with the topmost selected record, and that is not something I can really work with.

Furthermore, the above code retains the primary key value (ID) when moved into table `B`. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: AFAIK your query should be moving _all_ records from the `A` table which match the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes, I realize that using the primary key as a condition for moving the records is not the greatest way to go, but I seem to be unable to think of a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables `A` and `B` have the same columns for records filtering, you can just use `WHERE` clause used for searching rows in `A` table. But in some cases it may be difficult, especially if user is able to filter the subform manually. In this case you can create WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE [ID] in (1,3,5,7....)
```

If there are a lot of rows in the subform, this SQL may exceed SQL string length limit, so it's reasonable to split the moving into few chunks:

```
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strWhere As String
Dim strSQL As String

Const lngChunkSize = 100

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rst.MoveFirst

    Do Until rst.EOF
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        'Collect keys
        strWhere = strWhere & rst!ID & ","
        rst.MoveNext

        If lngCounter Mod lngChunkSize = 0 Or rst.EOF Then
            'chunk is full or end operations, move rows
            strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1) 'remove last coma
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO B ([a], [b], [c]) " & _
                     "SELECT [a], [b], [c] From A where ID in (" & strWhere & ")"

            'use ADO, it supports longer strings
            CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

            strSQL = "DELETE * From A where ID in (" & strWhere & ")"
            CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

            strWhere = ""
        End If
    Loop
End If
```

This way works much faster than one-by one looping thru the recordset. The speed is similar to using "normal" WHERE clause with all conditions.
Chunk size=100 was most optimal for performance in my case, you can try different chunk sizes and find most optimal size for your table.

Comment: Relatively new to Access:  

I tried running your code, but I am getting a `Run-Time error '424': Object required` report. I have read that record selections are lost after clicking on a button in earlier versions of Access.
Is this still the case, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also `strSQL = "INSERT INTO B ([a], [b], [c]) " & _
                 "SELECT [a], [b], [c] From A where ID in (" & strWhere & ")"`

Where do I find the documentation for converting strings into a list of numbers? In your above code, in the first loop, I noticed that `strWhere` is treated as a string, but it's followed in
the above by `" & strWhere & "`, Whereas I had to do something different, and add in `strID` at the end.

Comment: I guess my question here is... how do I define rst such that it conforms to what I have highlighted in my subform?

Comment: It was just a core code as an idea, of course you need to declare variables and set the recordset. I edited the answer. Recordset `rst` is a copy of form's recordset. List of keys created by line `strWhere = strWhere & rst!ID & ","`

Comment: I think my question wasn't exactly clear... How do I pass on the record selection? If I select multiple records in a subform, and click a button, the selection is immediately lost. I can't clone a copy of my record selection if it's lost. I want to select a number of records in the subform (datasheet), and then click a button on the main form that acts on those records. I think I understand what you're doing in your code above, but as far as I can tell, it assumes that `Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone` is valid. How do I pass my record selection from my subform, before anything is done?

Comment: You can look, for instance, at this thread: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1669535

Comment: That doesn't appear to be in datasheet view... I think I've figured out a bit of this though: If I include `rst.Move frm.SelTop - 1` immediately after `rst.MoveFirst`, Access will refer to my first selected record. I am unable to get the Selection Height, however. I am using [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1670575/7633721), and seem to be able to keep the selection height on exit, but I do not know how to pass it on to my main form. Is there a way to directly call upon  `m_SelNumRecs` directly in the link given, while in the main form?

Comment: At the end of the link I gave earlier you can find the class, which allows to access selected rows in any part of form's code, there is an example of using it, class members MSI.FirstRecord and MSI.LastRecord allow you to  cycle thru selected rows.

Comment: I just reread that. Not sure if it would be of use. Is there any particular reason to use that, over say, a non-visible text box that simply stores the value? I mean, it's clearly more elegant to use the linked code, but it seems to be rather tedious. I guess the single benefit is that this would work for all datasheets on different forms?

Comment: Yes, I think invisible field should also work fine, and yes, if you have a lot of forms it would be better to use the class in order to do not copy-paste main code