# Form.Seltop not selecting top most record

Tags: ms-access, vba

A followup to this question: [Moving records from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502250/moving-records-from-one-table-to-another)

I have a subform attached to a form. On highlighting a form and clicking something else (exit), it sends the number of rows highlighted to the main form via text box control.

```
Set frm = Forms!Form.[subform_subform].Form
Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone

recordStart = frm.SelTop - 1
recordEnd = recordStart + Me.SH - 1

Debug.Print Me.SH
Debug.Print recordStart
Debug.Print recordEnd
```

Where `Me.SH` is the number of rows selected. (Using http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1499722)

When selecting the rows from top to bottom, I get as an output for `recordStart` the top row that I have selected. But when I select the rows from bottom to top, I instead get the last row for `recordStart`. Is there a way to prevent this? The second link (as well as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194148.aspx) above implies that this should not happen. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's you that label the records "start" and "end".

To Access there is a "Top" record selected and a "height" (count) of records selected no matter how the user (or your code) selected the records.

If you wish a different sequence of selected records, apply the needed sorting first, then select the records.

Comment: Yes, I was under the assumption that `SelTop` selects the top most record. `recordStart` just moves the indices because of initialization issues. So for a column of records [0,1,2,3,4,5], if I highlight 1 and 2 from top to bottom, my code (not attached), spits out whatever is in rows 1 and 2. But if I select [1,2] from bottom to top, my code (the Debug.Print above should be sufficient) spits out [2,3]. That is, it is assuming the bottom of my rectangle (of selected records) is the top of my rectangle. I am assuming that somehow `SelTop` is being misread on my exit event. Is that possible?

Comment: I see. But what is `Me.SH`? Try using `.SelHeight`.

Comment: `.SelHeight` is lost on subform exit (clicking any buttons on the main form), so I made use of a textbox control `SH` on the main form. `.SelHeight` is passed on to `Me.SH` on exit. `Debug.Print Me.SH` outputs the correct number of rows.

Comment: Well, then something else must be going on in your code. I cannot replicate your reported behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out, and I believe this is a result of the way form selections work: On exit, parametres such as `.SelHeight` are lost, as expected. `.SelTop`, however, works differently.

Say `[Subform]` is in datasheet view, and is a `[Subform]` of `[Form]`:

```
Set frm = Forms![Form].[Subform].Form
Debug.Print frm.SelTop
```

If you were to select the records from top to bottom, then `frm.SelTop` will obviously be your first selected form.

But if you were to select from bottom to top, then `frm.SelTop` will be your bottom row, because it was the first selected row.

That is, whatever you click first will be `frm.SelTop`, because for whatever reason Access passes that on as `frm.SelTop`.

One way to solve this, besides using a bunch of public variables ([Moving records from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502250/moving-records-from-one-table-to-another)) is to create a textbox control for `.SelTop`, and pass the `.SelTop` value to your textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you question:
You want to use selTop and SelHeight to refer to a selection on a Access Form. 
But selTop is not returning the top row of the selection, but the first row you click when selecting
For ex if you select from top-down the third and forth row you get: selTop=3, selHeight= 2
But if you select from bottom-up you get selTop=4 and SelHeigh=2

Also you know that usually the selection is lost when clicking on a button, so it has to be saved. I guess this is what "Me.SH" means, because selHeight is always zero when accessed inside a button click event. You have probably save the value on SubForm_Exit event

The solution is that you have to save both selTop and SelHeigh at the same time:

```
Private Sub MySubForm_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

  With MySubForm.Form
    SH = .SelHeight
    TOP = .SelTop
  End With

End Sub
```

Not doing that, the selection is cleared and selTop is set to the current selected Record which is the bottom record (when you select bottom up)