# 3021 runtime error at rs.Move when selecting record in the subform

Tags: ms-access

I edited code by referring to [How do I access the selected rows in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access). But I got runtime error of 3021 at `RS.Move F.SelTop - 1` with my code even though m_SelNumRecs is not zero. I am not sure if I have to add additional code to my code.
I have a form including a subform of frm_SubPerson. I select record(s) on the frm_SubPerson and want to conver the record(s) into pdf.

```
Public m_SelNumRecs As Long
Public m_SelTopRec As Long
Public m_CurrentRec As Long

Private Sub cmdConvert()
   Dim mSelTop As Long
   Dim mSelHeight As Long
   Dim F As Form
   Dim RS As Recordset
   Dim filePath As String
   Dim i As Integer

   ' Get the form and its recordset.
   Set F = Me.frm_SubPerson.Form
   Set RS = F.RecordsetClone

   If m_SelNumRecs = 0 Then
      MsgBox "no record is selected."
      Exit Sub
   End If

   ' Move to the first selected record.
   RS.Move F.SelTop - 1 '3021 error

   For i = 1 To m_SelNumRecs
       DoCmd.OpenReport "report_Person", acViewPreview, , "report_Person.chName=" & "'" & RS!chName.Value & "'"
       filePath = "D:\report_Person\" & "report_Person" & RS!chName & "_" & RS!chNum & "_" & RS!reYear.Value & "Year" & RS!reMonth & "Month" & ".pdf"
       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, filePath
       DoCmd.Close acReport, "report_Person"
       RS.MoveNext
   Next i

   RS.Close
   Set RS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub frm_SubPerson_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
   With frm_SubPerson.Form
   m_SelNumRecs = .SelHeight
   m_SelTopRec = .SelTop
   m_CurrentRec = .CurrentRecord
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Since your code is behind a button, I guess that **Here's the catch** applies here. Check also the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670575/3820271

Comment: Have you inspected the actual value returned by SelTop function?  Have you inspected the current position of the RS recordset?  Without testing myself, I do not know if the RecordsetClone method returns an object at the exact same position as the Form displays.  Also, SetTop returns the top of the selected rows in the UI, but that does not necessarily mean it always returns the current Recordset row.  You need to look at documentation for both Move and SelTop and really consider whether the values are always compatible (i.e. whether your code really makes sense in all cases).

Comment: I inspedted SelHeight, SelTop, CurrentRecord and AbsolutePosition. AbsolutePosition was inspected with `Debug.Print RS.AbsolutePosition` which was right in front of `If m_SelNumRecs = 0 Then`. But I don't understand why RS.AbsolutePosition was changed whenever I clicked the button for cmdPrintSel_Click. Here is my try. I selected 1 row on the `frm_SubPerson` and click button for `cmdPrintSel three times. The values of (SelHeight, SelTop, CurrentRecord) remaind 1(s) but AbsolutePosition were changed like this. 0->1->-1 I don't understand why the AbsolutePosition was changed.