# MS-Access. Update checkboxes from selected records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a button that when user selects records and clicks the button, checkbox in each records would be updated to Yes.

So that my user would be able to choose which customers he would like to print labels by himself.

The problem is that user has to click each checkbox which is very time consuming, and I am a newbie at coding.

Thanks!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access

Comment: To be honest, I did read it before asking but with my coding level, I don't really understand it. Would you mind showing how to apply that in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Create a query, which updates the field with flag in base table to True and run it by clicking your "Select All" button

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear.
The problem is that user would like to flag each record himself every time he wants to print the labels which is time consuming.

The only way he can do it now, is to click each record one by one. It would be great to let him select multiple records and change the checkbox value to Yes at once.