# Use field from selected row in table or query MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS Access, I have a table "files" with i.a. the fields "title" and “fileLocation”.
What I would like to have, is a button that opens the file to which the selected record is referring.
In other words:

1. I open the table "files"
2. perform a search on the field "title" for the file I would like to open
3. usually the right entire record is now selected
4. a click on the button should op the file

Of course, I can also put the entire path in the “fileLocation”, but the drive letter changes from time to time…

The VBA-code behind the button should be something like this:

```
Sub buttonClickHandler()
 Dim fLocation As String
 fLocation = files."current selected record".fileLocation

 If (Dir("D\fileLocation") <> "")
 Then (Application.FollowHyperlink "D\fileLocation")
 Elseif (Dir("E\fileLocation") <> "")                       
 Then (Application.FollowHyperlink "E\fileLocation")
 ...
 Else (MsgBox "File not found")
End Sub
```

I have found a similar question here: 
[How do I access the selected rows in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access)
But I still haven’t found how to use that code with tables or queries instead of forms

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's simple: you just use a form. Tables and queries are not intended for such things, forms are. You can use datasheet view to have a similar look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth/) and the answer to [How do I access the selected rows in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access) did indeed the job.

1. Create a form from the table and use the view as datasheet (before I only knew forms in column view)
2. Set timer interval to 1000
3. Create a class object like:

---

```
Dim previousSelection As Integer

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  previousSelection = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
  If Me.SelHeight <> 1 Or Me.SelTop = previousSelection Then Exit Sub

  previousSelection = Me.SelTop
  With Me.RecordsetClone
    .MoveFirst
    .Move Me.SelTop - 1
    openFile ("path/to/file")
  End With
End Sub

Sub openFile(fileName As String)
  If (Dir("D:\" & fileName) <> "") Then
    Application.FollowHyperlink ("D:\" & fileName)
  ElseIf (Dir("E:\" & fileName) <> "") Then
    Application.FollowHyperlink ("E:\" & fileName)
  Else
    MsgBox ("File not found")
  End If
End Sub
```

Every time you change the selected row, the related file will be opened.