# How to make the checkbox populate when selecting records?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I put the mouse cursor on the "Record Selection Area".
I highlight several entries.

[image]

---

### Update - 1

**Situation 1 - ок.**
I select from top to bottom (4, 5, 6).
Result: checkboxes are filled correctly - 4, 5, 6.

**Situation 2 - problem.**
I perform selection down-up (6, 5, 4).
Result: checkboxes are populated mirror-by-6, 7, 8.
[image]
[image]

Checkboxes are filled in mirrored.
**Question.**
How to make checkboxes populate correctly regardless of the direction in which records are selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the selected rows in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669946/how-do-i-access-the-selected-rows-in-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you can do this way using the *RecordsetClone*:

```vb
Private Sub Form_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Height  As Long
    Dim Top     As Long
    Dim Offset  As Long
    Dim Count   As Long

    Height = Me.SelHeight

    If Height > 1 Then
        Top = Me.SelTop
        Me.SelHeight = 0
        If Me.CurrentRecord > Top Then
            Offset = Height - 1
        End If

        Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone
        Records.MoveFirst
        Records.Move -Offset, Me.Bookmark
        For Count = 0 To Height - 1
            Records.Edit
                Records!PurchaseArea.Value = True
            Records.Update
            Records.MoveNext
        Next
        Records.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: See `Update - 1`.